# invoking capistrano from PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, capistrano

I have a CodeIgniter app which has a controller to invoke Capistrano. Like so:

```
class Deploy extends Controller {
```

```
function deploy()
{
    parent::Controller();   
}

function index()
{
    $output = shell_exec("cap deploy");
    echo $output;
}
```

}

For some reason if I call shell_exec('ls -a') I get output. But calling cap deploy does nothing and returns nothing. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is 'cap' in the $PATH of the user (apache?) that is running the web server?

Comment: Good point. Is there an easy way to do this without logging in as apache user?

Comment: Trying specifying the absolute path to the 'cap' binary